# Failed Context Types: Required context `router.setRouteLeaveHook` was not specified in `Link`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, stormpath

I am getting the above warning when my nav bar loads and I'm at a complete loss, but feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I am using react (15.0.2), react-router(2.0.0), react-stormpath (1.1.0), stormpath (0.16.0)

Navbar component:

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div className="container">
        <div id="navbar-collapse" className="collapse navbar-collapse" >
        <div className="navbar-header">
            <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Title Logo</Link>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav" >
            <Authenticated inGroup="admin" >
                <li><Link to="/createCourse">Create Event</Link></li>
            </Authenticated>
            <Authenticated>
                <li><Link to="/findEvents">Find Event</Link></li>
            </Authenticated>
            <Authenticated>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            </Authenticated>
        </ul>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <NotAuthenticated>
                <li><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><LoginLink /></li>
            </NotAuthenticated>
            <NotAuthenticated>
                <li><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><Link to="/register">Create Account</Link></li>
            </NotAuthenticated>
            <Authenticated>
                <li><LogoutLink /></li>
            </Authenticated>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Router:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
    <HomeRoute path="/" component={MasterPage} >
         <IndexRoute component={home} />
         <LoginRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
         <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationPage} />
         <AuthenticatedRoute inGroup="admin" path="/createCourse" component={AppIndex} />
         <AuthenticatedRoute><Route path="/findEvents" component={FindEvents} /></AuthenticatedRoute>
         <Route path="/about" component={About} />
         <AuthenticatedRoute><Route path="/event/:id" component={AppIndex} /></AuthenticatedRoute>
    </HomeRoute>
</Router>
```

Does my nav bar component need to override the setRouteLeaveHook function? Does this need to be done in my router?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an incompatibility issue with React-Router and the Stormpath-React SDK. I'm going to look into it.

Cheers!

Robin